# How to know the entire text of HTMLTableDataCellElement is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a table which have editable columns and when the text in the editable column is selected, how can we check using java-script whether the entire text of the HTMLTableDataCellElement is selected or not?

Like for input field there is a way

`input.selectionStart == 0 && input.selectionEnd == input.value.length`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try.

```js
document.onmouseup = (e) => {
  e = e || window.event;
  const target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  const selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  if (target.innerHTML === selection) {
    alert('Cell fully selected!');
  }
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Dolor sit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Dolor sit amet dolor sit amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum dolor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```